# Not able to add the second refernce, as i add second citation in .bib file and build the file from latex ,the changes are not shown

Tags: latex, pdflatex, bibtex, bibliography, citations

basic structure of my latex  file is :-

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
% all the content goes here
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio.bib}
\end{document}
```

biblio.bib is the file where the bibliography is stored. contents of biblio.bib file are :-

```
@inproceedings{sase,
  title={High-performance complex event processing over streams},
  author={Wu, Eugene and Diao, Yanlei and Rizvi, Shariq},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 2006 ACM SIGMOD international conference on Management of data},
  pages={407--418},
  year={2006},
  organization={ACM}
}


@inproceedings{wu2006,
  title={High-performance complex event processing over streams},
  author={Wu, Eugene and Diao, Yanlei and Rizvi, Shariq},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 2006 ACM SIGMOD international conference on Management of data},
  pages={407--418},
  year={2006},
  organization={ACM}
}


@inproceedings{ishi1995,
  title={A synchronization mechanism for continuous media in multimedia communications},
  author={Ishibashi, Yutaka and Tasaka, Shuji},
  booktitle={INFOCOM'95. Fourteenth Annual Joint Conference of the IEEE Computer and Communications Societies. Bringing Information to People. Proceedings. IEEE},
  pages={1010--1019},
  year={1995},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

but the reference output is shown just for first citation, while the other two are not being shown.I have seen some videos which advised that after the citation is added , the build process has to be done in this order
1. build using BibTeX once
2. build using PdfLatex twice.

I have followed this procedure , yet not able to see the results.Please help me . if you need some more information please let me know.

Comment: errr, just confirming, have you used \cite{<label>} in the main contents for all 3 references?

Comment: yes, that was the issue . When i included \cite{<myLabel>}  and refreshed it , then it was shown.Thanks a lot for help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the citations in reference section we have to mention them in  the text  using `\cite{<myLabel>}` , and refresh the page, then they will be shown